# Find ID of HTML element which called JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a three button navigation panel, comprising of three divs and an anchor. On mouse over, myFunction() assigns a class to the three divs and anchor tag, for styling purposes.

```
<nav>
    <div id="btn1" class="button" onMouseOver="myFunction();">
    <div id="btn_bdr1">
    <div id="btn_bdr2">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="btn3" class="button" onMouseOver="myFunction();">
    <div id="btn_bdr1">
    <div id="btn_bdr2">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>

    <div id="btn2" class="button"  onMouseOver="myFunction();">
    <div id="btn_bdr1">
    <div id="btn_bdr2">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

What I need to do is find the ID of the div which called myFunction(), so I can make a change within the function to only the calling div, not all three.

Using JavaScript only, how can I go about doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is two ways you can do is

1) Send an argument to the method with the div's name

**Example**

```
<div id="btn1" class="button" onMouseOver="myFunction('btn1')">
```

2) Send the element this

**Example**

```
<div id="btn1" class="button" onMouseOver="myFunction(this)">
```

In the javascript you can then do

```
myFunction(element) {
    //element is now the element you clicked on
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fyllekanin, your answer is the closest to what I am after, though I've gone with myFunction(this.id) as I need the id, not the element. I'll update the post with the actual code block used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event` object and look at the target (`e.target`). This is a reference to the element itself so to get the ID you would simply access the element's `id` property. (`e.target.id`)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(function(ele, ind) {
  ele.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target, e.target.id);
  })
});
```

```css
.a {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: solid black 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" id="one"></div>
<div class="a" id="two"></div>
<div class="a" id="three"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `this.event.target` from `myFunction()` to determine which element generated the event.

For example:

```
myFunction() {
   console.log("I was called by: ", this.event.target);
}
```